# monitoring cpu and memory usage of processes

Tags: java, process

what is the best way for running some other processes and *monitoring* them inside Java?

by monitoring I mean checking their CPU and memory usage and their running state (Running or Finished).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not provide this kind of information.  You'll need to make operating system specific calls.